# EMV Contact Card Issuer Public Key Validation

Tags: smartcard, public-key, ca, emv

I have problem with validation of EMV contact card issuer public key.
Document says:
"Verify that the concatenation of RID, Certification Authority Public Key Index, and Certificate Serial Number is valid. If not, SDA has failed."
I concatenated these and sending them to SHA1 function to gain a hash value that will be compared with the public key's hash value and i took a comparision error; because their values are not equal. Did I misunderstand the document?

Answer (score 0):

Wich document do you refer?

Normaly you would get a CDOL in the GPO Response. The data for SDA should concatenated as described in this CDOL.

Remark: You should use DDA at minimum as supported.